# How was this independent navigation done?

Tags: uwp

This is a screenshot from the Microsoft Math app. I want to get a similar behavior in my app, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Everything in the docs seems to be focused on single page applications, and I guess my Google Fu skill isn't high enough find anything about this.

[image]

This app has two panes that can navigate independently. I'm guessing this is a `SplitView`, but `Frame.Navigate()` is just going to put a whole new Page on top of this one. Is there a component that's equivalent to iOS's UINavigationController that can handle this automatically?

Note: I'm not looking for a full implementation, just an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Frame` control to `SplitView.Content` and show pages inside it.

XAML:

```
<SplitView>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame x:Name="Fr_Main"/>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

C#:

```
 Fr_Main.Navigate(typeof(YourPage));
```

**EDIT:**

As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.frame.aspx), the `Frame` property refers to frame in which is the current page displayed.

Comment: Can a Frame be embedded into other components (e.g. Grid or Flyout)? The docs aren't very clear on how and where you can use it.

Comment: Of course it could be in Grid or StackPanel etc. I'm not sure about the Flyout but it may work too. Just try it :-)